# jQuery Image Slider - with images on either side of the main image

Tags: jquery, image, slider

I realise there are hundreds of tutorials on the net on how to create a jQuery image slider. However, none of them quite relate to what I'm trying to do...

I have a set of images that are about 350px in height and 800px wide. What I really want to do is to have these images at the top of the page, and have them slide through (like seen in many sliders). The only difference is, I really want the other 2 images on either side of the main image in focus. So when the image slides in, you can see it from the left. And the image that has just left the main focus can still be seen it from the right. Obviously the left and right images to the sides of the main image will be slightly off the page.

The reason I want this is so I can have a full size website that caters for all resolutions. Also, I plan to make this site responsive so when the page shrinks, the 2 pictures on either side are no longer needed. I hope I've made this clear. I'm just wondering if there are any examples of this out there?

As a "nice to have", it would also be great to have an image selecter too!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this...... 
[Hero Carousel](http://www.paulwelsh.info/jquery-plugins/hero-carousel/) 
it might fit your description. 
Here's another link which might gather to your need. 
http://jsfiddle.net/JCQ6Q/15/ 
Vote up if it helps you :) all the best